# Selenium Webdriver clicks stale buttons in a "for loop" iteration

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dom, web-scraping

I am using the Selenium webdriver to click a list of identical buttons (input elements) on an HTML page.

My Python script for this purpose clicks a button that opens a new webpage, and then my script goes back to the original page with buttons.

The simplified HTML page looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" name=".submit" value="Details" />
<input type="submit" name=".submit" value="Details" />
<input type="submit" name=".submit" value="Details" />
...
<input type="submit" name=".submit" value="Details" />
```

And my simplified python script looks like this:

```py
# buttons is a list of button elements
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[value='Details']")

# for i in the length of the list of buttons
for i in range(len(buttons)):

    # click that specfic button
    # !! Error occurs here on the second iteration of the for loop !!
    buttons[i].click()

    # go back one page
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")

    # wait 5 seconds before moving on to the next ith button
    time.sleep(5)
```

However, this script returns a StaleElementReferenceException error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\laure\Desktop\Work\covid-sirna\src\scv2_genome_mirdb.py", line 49, in <module>
    buttons[i].click()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)
```

Previous answers to similar questions on Stack Overflow point that the error is caused by the button elements not being properly loaded when they are clicked, and suggest setting a delay with `time.sleep()` to allow proper loading.

However, the `StaleElementReferenceException` error still occurs with this recommendation.

Why are the buttons still stale after a 5-second delay? And what is a solution to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redefine the buttons variable in each loop iteration. The reference to the buttons will no longer be valid after you reload the page. You need to obtain a new reference each time.

Basically just put the first line into the loop.